# Where does the code to add a lightbox effect go?

Tags: plugins

I am not a developer but am working on a Wordpress site for my church.

It can be found in its "under construction" stage at [Seminole Heights Baptist Church Test Site](http://tobonto.com/shbc/)

I installed the plugin for [WidgetKit Lite for Wordpress](http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit)

It installed successfully

On the slider of the church site, the first slider is a picture of me waving that reads "First Time?  Watch our welcome video" that goes to a youtube page with no relevance.  Its just there to test video.

What I want to do is create an effect that pops out a box. I apparently cannot post more than one link until I have 10 reputation points but the site I wanted to reference is for [Greenway Carpet](http://www.greenwaycarpet.com/)

I like how the background goes dark and the video box pops out becoming the focal point.

Comment: Looks like you need to add another plugin to use in conjunction with WidgetKit Lite.  Try the [Video Lightbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/)

Answer (score 0):

install the [Simple Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/) and all images will automatically be shown in lightbox..

or you can have a look at this jquery lightbox. [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)